# knockoutjs, observables updating each other

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have view model with 3 fields

```
dateStart = ko.observable();
dateEnd = ko.observable();
days = ko.observable();
```

assuming startDate is selected, whenever endDate is selected days field needs to be updated (days = endDate - startDate).

Also when days field is updated i need to calculate endDate (endDate = startDate + days).

how can this be done with knockoutjs ?

Thank You!

I've tried
http://jsfiddle.net/NfG4C/6/, but my js always throws too musch recursion exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, you basically need 2 things.

1. You want to calculate the "days" field whenever someone selects the
   "endDate" [assuming they have selected the "startDate" ofcourse]
2. You want to recalculate the "endDate" field whenever someone changes the
   "days" field

One way to solve this would be to use a "writeable" computed Observable [[http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html]](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html). Please go through the link for details, but in general term, a 'writeable computed observable' is something whose value is 'computed' based on some 'other' observable(s) and vice-versa.

I took the liberty to modify your fiddle and change the "days" as a computed observable. Please take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/dJQnu/5/

```
this.days = ko.computed({
    read: function () {
        //debugger;
        // here we simply need to calculate the days as => (days = endDate - startDate)
        if (that.dateStart() && that.dateEnd()) {
            var vacDayCounter = 0;
            for (var curDate = new Date(that.dateStart()); curDate <= that.dateEnd(); curDate = curDate.addDays(1)) {
                if (isDateCountsAsVacation(curDate)) {
                    vacDayCounter++;
                }
            }
            //that.days(vacDayCounter);
            return vacDayCounter;
        }
    },
    write: function (newDays) {
        if (newDays && !isNaN(newDays) && that.dateStart()) {
            var tmpEndDate = new Date(that.dateStart())
            appliedDays = 0;
            while (appliedDays < newDays) {
                if (isDateCountsAsVacation(tmpEndDate)) {
                    appliedDays++;
                }
                tmpEndDate = tmpEndDate.addDays(1);
            }
            if (tmpEndDate) {
                that.dateEnd(tmpEndDate);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

If you notice, I simply reused your code (logic) for the read and write part. During read, we are "computing" the value for the observable itself, in this case the "days" and during write (which fires anytime the user changes the actual "days" input value) we are recalculating the "dateEnd" field.

Please let me know if you have any other question.

Hope this helps.

Thanks.

Comment: thx for reply Sir )
I think thats the solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You get a recusive problem because when updating the observables from a subscription will also trigger that observables subscribe method.

You need to add a fourth member, updatedFromSubscriber

set it to false from tbe beginning, in each subscribe method add

```
if(this.updatedFromSubscriber)
 return;
```

and just before updating the observable do

```
this.updatedFromSubscriber = true
```

set it to false after updating the observable